# How would I put limits to the char's length?

Tags: java, char, switch-statement

Here is the question: Write a Java program that asks the user to provide a single character from the alphabet. Print Vowel or Consonant, depending on the user input. If the user input is not a letter (between a and z or A and Z), or is a string of length > 1, print an appropriate, descriptive error message.

I have made a switch statement that successfully tells if you have a vowel or a consonant but I can't figure out how to give an error message if the length of what the user types in is more than one character.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class VowelKL{
public static void main(String[] args){

int i=0;
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a single letter from the alphabet: ");
char letter=input.next().charAt(0);

switch(letter)
{
case 'a' :
case 'e' :
case 'i' :
case 'o' :
case 'u' : 
case 'A' :
case 'E' :
case 'I' : 
case 'O' :
case 'U' : i++;
}
if(i==1)
System.out.println("You entered the letter " + letter + " and it is a Vowel!");
else
if((letter>='a' && letter<='z')||(letter>='A' && letter<='Z'))
System.out.println("You entered the letter " + letter + " and it is a Consonant!");
else
System.out.println("You did not enter a single character from the alphabet, please try again.");



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
public int length() {  
      return i.length;  
  }
```

There are a few ways of doing this and the above is only an example but the `.length()` property will get you an int value of the length of the string. In the above case we are then returning the int as a value.

In your case you could make a new int variable and then assign it with the length.

```
int x = letter.length()
```

This will get the length of the string to an int value. You can then take that and write an if statement for when it is above or below the value of 1.

**EDIT:**

I quickly wrote this in java and it seems to work as intended. Hope that helps point you in the correct direction. Note that you would need to change your variable `letter` from a `char` to a `String`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a single letter from the alphabet: ");
    String letter= input.nextLine();
    
    if (letter.length() == 1)
        System.out.println("Only one letter was entered");
    else
        System.out.println("Either no letter or more than one letter was entered");         
}
```

Comment: How would I change the variable `letter` from `char` to a `string`?

Comment: just do like I have done. I changed 'char letter = input.next().charAt(0);' to 'String letter= input.nextLine();'. You wont wont be able to use the .length() property on a char. So i'd use a String instead

Answer (score -1):

As you are already specifying in the user input command that user input is allowed only at index 0 i.e. charAt(0). So there is no other way to extract the index position of that character value. Unless you have to cast that particular character in the string type and then you can access  String's

str.lastIndexOf(char) method to provide the restriction .
which is not the best practice to do.

Comment: Not very useful answer.

Comment: @blagerweij , can you suggest something better ?

Comment: The problem with the question is that the user input is immediately stored in a single character: `char letter=input.next().charAt(0);`. Casting a char to a String does not solve that, storing the result of `input.next()` in a String, then check the length of that String would solve the problem.

Comment: @blagerweij, appreciate it but he is asking for a  limit not casting and length verification